# Difference between -match ... and | where {$_ -match ...}

Tags: arrays, powershell

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while now, but I can't seem to figure out the difference between these two. In particular, the differences as they pertains to an array of data:

```
PS C:>$myarray = "a", "ab", "abc"
PS C:>$myarray -match "b"
ab
abc
PS C:>$myarray | where {$_ -match "b"}
ab
abc
```

Can anyone help me understand what, if any, the differences are between these two options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is none at least in the result. One if applying a comparison operator to an array (which means it is applied to each array element and those where it returns `$true` will be returned). The other is passing the array to a cmdlet that does filtering. The result is the same.

You could get creative and solve the same thing in yet another way:

```
$myarray | foreach { if ($_ -match 'b') { $_ } }
```

Note however, that when the left operand *isn't* an array, the result is different:

```
PS Home:\> ,'b' -match 'b'
b
PS Home:\> 'b' -match 'b'
True
```

So if you have a variable where you're not sure whether it's an array or not you could either force it to be one:

```
@($foo) -match 'b'
```

or use `Where-Object` which will do the right thing.

---

Personally I tend to just use the operator directly when writing PowerShell code at the console. It makes for a nice concise `grep` equivalent as well:

```
(gc file) -match 'regex'
```

(I should really start using `Select-String` more often, though.)

But I use the “proper” way with `Where-Object` when writing scripts that need to be robust or others have to read/maintain.

Comment: Oh totally, I could tell that the results always seemed to be the same, but I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some detail or minutia that made them distinct in their use.

Thanks a ton (especially for the edits!), that clears things up for me!

Comment: Just my 2 cents, I've found `Select-String` is _very_ fast.

Comment: @sodawillow Curious, how might I go about utilizing `Select-String` for something like this? I've read about it a bit, but I don't quite understand what it does.

Comment: I think it's more indicated if you need to search for a string in a (big) file. I use this on a daily basis with a CSV file holding around 30 cols and 50k rows. 2 or 3 secs to get all matches. It tends to get a bit slow if you have _a lot_ of matches, though. Your mileage may vary, as they say.

Comment: @JoshS.: I guess that was a comment to my last paragraph, which shows something I commonly do (using the operator directly on an array), even though it's not a good solution because it can be slow with large inputs.

Comment: And if you really need performance, the ".Net native methods" road is usually a wonderland.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. Yea, I'm mainly looking for clean ways to filter through arrays of tens of items, so performance is probably not my biggest concern haha. I'm just looking to expand my understanding of the language, so thanks for the input!

Comment: Regarding .NET methods, those that use a scriptblock callback (e.g. `$array.Where({...})`) will have much worse performance than PS without a scriptblock (e.g. `$array -match 'value'`) because in PS the invocation overhead of a user-function/scriptblock is relatively huge.

Answer (score 2):

- `$array -match 'value'` - directly checks each value's string representation which is very fast (especially noticeable on large arrays)
- `$array | where { $_ -match 'value' }` - executes a *scriptblock* on each item, hence:

  - invocation overhead (noticeable on large arrays where it can slow down processing a lot)
  - flexibility and complex conditions
  - properties can be used
  - extra actions can be performed